# how to scroll up auto in scroll view with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, native

I making a question app the questions page should be scrolling up when a question have an answer . How can I make this .e.g I want when an question have answer 100px scrolling up . How can I make thnks

`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".Screens.GamePlayFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gameplay_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gameapptop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeofcountdown_game_screen"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCounterIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gameovercountericon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/textViewCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCounterIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="2/17"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutGame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            >

            <!--Question 1 -->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeofquestion3"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/questionLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/qRoof1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/q1"
                        android:layout_width="270dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/q1"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`
How can I make this .e.g I want when an question have answer 100px scrolling up . How can I make thnks

Comment: I think a better way is to use a RecylcerView instead of a LinearLayout. With the RecyclerView it is very easy to scroll to a specific question. `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(<position>) `. Adapter View is then the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: I understand but I should use linear layout . are there any way ? thnks

Comment: You can scroll with the `ScrollView` and the [scrollTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#scrollTo(int,%20int)) function

Comment: val sv = binding.linearLayoutGame
        sv.smoothScrollTo(0, sv.getScrollY() + sv.getHeight()) . yes ı know I use like this . but it not always working . only works once .

Comment: thnks . I succesed .val layout = binding.linearLayoutGame
                layout.smoothScrollTo(0, layout.getScrollY() + layout.getHeight());